# In the context of silicon wafer manufacturing, what is the relative frequency of the three major plurals of "die"?

Tags: word-choice

A die is a unit of circuitry and substrate that occurs on a wafer and is cut out from its (often identical) neighbors.

I often hear this pluralized as: dies, dice, or die. I believe all may be correct. How common is each one? Is it at all regional?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrowly focused. It It belongs on another site, perhaps in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Well, before you do, let's tell the OP something.  The "dice" plural is for gaming--the six-sided cubes, so the likely plural for die on a wafer is probably either die or dies.  Pluralizing it as dice is likely to be an office joke.

Comment: @Xanne I think it's a mistake from people used to gaming dice, but a mistake that's very common is ends up being right if that's just how people use the language.

Comment: Well, perhaps Edwin was right in the first place.  But "dice" in the silicon chip industry is a verb meaning to slice up a wafer into dies, or cut it out, as the OP says.  "Dice" as a plural may be a mishearing. I haven't seen "dice" as a plural of die in/on a wafer.

Comment: Actually Wikipedia says what the OP says--that all three are in use.  What the frequencies are would be difficult to determine and probably different in speech and in the literature.